# Python web crawler not printing the results

Tags: python, web-crawler

It is not printing out any results and giving back a strange error as shown in the picture using pycharm.

[image]

Code I wrote:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def webcrawler(max_pages,url):
    page = 1
    if page <= max_pages:
        webpage = (url) + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        code_text = source_code.text
        soup_format = BeautifulSoup(code_text)
        for link in soup_format.findAll('a', {'class': 's-item__image-wrapper'}):
            href = str(url) + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print(href)
            print(title)
        page += 1

webcrawler(1, 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phone-Accessories/9394/bn_320095?_pgn=')
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: It's giving a warning saying to use a parser

Comment: Also, are you sure that the data you want to extract isn't loaded by JS and already exists in your `source_code`?

Comment: Are you looking to extract all the hyperlinks to the products in page?

Answer (score 0):

The warning message tells you exactly what to do to stop it from being raised. You just need to pass a parser to the `BeautifulSoup` that you instantiate on line 10 e.g.

```
soup_format = BeautifulSoup(code_text, features='html.parser')
```

However, there are some more issues with your code. Line 11 from the code in your original post:

```
        for link in soup_format.findAll('a', {'class': 's-item__image-wrapper'}):
```

Will return `None` as there are no `<a>` tags with the class `s-item__image-wrapper` - all tags with that class in the target page are `<div>`s.

I have a suggestion below that seems to capture what you're looking to scrape. It instead iterates across each `<div class="s-item__image">` which is something of a wrapper class around the item data you are looking to print. It then drills down to the first child `<a>` tag to get the item `href` and takes the `alt` attribute of the item `img` within the wrapper for the item description - have changed the print order of these and added a trailing new line in example below for readability.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def webcrawler(max_pages,url):
    page = 1
    if page <= max_pages:
        webpage = (url) + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        code_text = source_code.text
        soup_format = BeautifulSoup(code_text, features='html.parser')
        for wrapper in soup_format.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 's-item__image'}):
            href = str(url) + wrapper.find('a').get('href')
            title = wrapper.find('img').get('alt')
            print(title)
            print(href)
            print()
        page += 1

webcrawler(1, 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Cell-Phone-Accessories/9394/bn_320095?_pgn=')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am actually totally new to coding and your explanation was spot on <3

Comment: @RashikRahmanIshmum No worries :) I'd recommend always reading any warning, exception, error messages in future as they can often be very helpful in debugging your code - however there were deeper issues in the logic of your code in this case also. Best of luck on your journey